# C# - Search in List with array in WHERE clause

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite

C#

Ok, I have something like that:

```
var message = db.Table<Message>().Where(cond => cond.ID == messageID).Single();
message.Status = status;
```

But I'd like to change my `messageID` from `int` to `int[]`, so I will select all data where `cond.ID` is in my `int[] messageID`.
I need something like `.Where(cond => cond.ID IN messageID)`.
I don't want to do that in a way like:

```
foreach(var ID in messageID)
{
   message = db.Table<Message>.Where(cond => cond.ID == ID).Single();
   message.Status = status;
   db.Update(message);
}
```

I use SQLite, any help with update multiple rows at once will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This will do it:

```
var messages = db.Table<Message>().Where(msg => messageIDs.Contains(msg.ID));
```

Comment: Actually, I'm updating ObservableCollection. Is there a way to update all items with single line of code? ;)

Comment: @VladislavKasianenko You could potentially do (at the end) `.ToList().ForEach(msg => msg.Status = status);` - but I personally find that a bit ugly (creating a list just to update a property) and usually just use a foreach.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work.

```
var message = db.Table<Message>().Where(cond => messageIDs.Any(id => cond.ID == id).Single();
message.Status = status;
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
var messageIDs = new int[]; // assume it's filled
var result = db.Table<Message>().Where(cond => messageIDs.Contains(cond.ID));

foreach(var message in result)
    message.Status = status;

db.SaveChanges(); //or something similar.
```

It will return all the messages which ID's are present in the test array.

Be advised: `Contains` can translate to `OR` in SQL. It might perform badly. Especially when applied to `string`.

Meanwhile you can set the `status` for each message using a `foreach` loop. The ORM you are using might have something like `db.SaveChanges` which should send a single update query to the database.

Answer (score 0):

use the `.contains()` method

```
var message = db.Table<Message>().Where(cond => messageID.contains(cond.ID)).Single();
```